# Problem loading sketch to arduino MiniQ

Tags: arduino, error

This is the first time I have used [this product](http://littlebirdelectronics.com/products/4wd-miniq-complete-kit) (an Arduino-compatible robot) and I'm having some trouble. I've done this on 2 different boards now.

I select the serial port, load up the blink sketch....

First time - it loads beautifully and I get the Blink sketch I loaded.

I then change the values for a longer blink....load it and get the error

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

I get a pause as though its about to start loading the code....but then the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: glad to see you asking questions again!

Comment: Not sure, but this question could be related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14072/what-possible-ways-can-i-upload-sketches-to-arduiono-mega-chips

Answer (score 3):

That error usually means that AVRdude missed the window to send something before the bootloader dropped through to the already loaded sketch.

Some arduino bootloaders have a different wait-for-program delay (or none at all)
depending on the reset source (poweron, reset pin, or watchdog).

Do you have a schematic (didn't find one on DFR site)?  Are you applying reset the
same way each time, or differently the first time (power on vs reset-from-serial-DTR maybe?)

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset it while holding the button for some time, ive expereienced the same problem. What i found out helps me best when i get errors like those, is that resetting with a long button hold works for me. Eventhough that not be the original source of the problem. but i think it has something to do with how long the mcu takes to initialize before it will accept the flashing process.

Does this only come as soon as you try to change something ?
Your reset button may also be damaged.
Is your LED Pin13 on ?
Can you see action on the TX and RX line ?

Answer (score 1):

**The answer(workaround):**
Moving from an Ubuntu platform to Windows7 fix those problems for me.

**The context:**
I normally work on Ubuntu (currently 11.04) and using the Arduino 0022 software and Arduino UNO board.

I have 5 Atmega328p chips.  Out of the 5, 3 are not Working under Ubuntu (error 'not in sync' or 'not responding'), 1 I have to trick into working under Ubuntu by setting the download speed to 19200 and then back to 57600 and, finally, 1 that works just fine all the time!!!???!!!

For some reason they all work perfectly under Windows7 with the Arduino 0022 software.

I'll post here if I ever fix my problem on Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like a subset of this should be a comment, while a different subset should remain as an answer. Please make sure that your answers focus on the solution to the problem: "Me too" and other symptoms usually fit better as comments to the question.

Comment: I did some edits for clarity