# What possible ways can I upload sketches to Arduiono Mega chips?

Tags: arduino, avrdude

I have been updating the embedded code on a set of [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega) chips.

I have been performing the upload via USB. Unfortunately, this is extremely unreliable. I get an error along the lines of

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 
avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x51
```

I simply get another board (we have a whole shelf full of them) and work with that one until it stops working as well.

According to [this forum](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1248528012/all), I'm not the only one who's having this problem.

I've heard (somebody telling me he heard from somebody else) that the USB transfer is unreliable, and that there's some other way.

Can anyone tell me if I'm hearing correctly, and if so, what the upload method is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way is to program is via the In Circuit Serial Progamming (ICSP) connector - with an appropriate interface like the STK-500 or [this one](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825).

Comment: I've ordered one Pocket AVR dude. We'll see if it works.

Comment: It works! Now I just have to figure out how to generate the sketch... http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16321/creating-a-sketch-hex-file-from-a-pde-file

Answer (score 1):

As long as it has the boot loader you could use your serial port, as a work around. On another arduino, I used a max232 chip hooked up to the TX and RX bypassing the USB to serial connection and pointed the arduino SW to that comm port, worked like a charm except you have to hit reset before you send the new firmware, no automatic reset.

From what I notice is that if i leave my arduino connected to the PC/USB line(linux), after awhile(30mins+) I try and program it and it gets a similar message.